# SOCKETS - Using multiple IP's server

Tags: php, sockets, ip, plesk

I have a sub PLESK server with multiple IP.

When I make a connection SOCKET, my server always uses the same IP. Do you know, how is it possible to use other IP from my server?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You have to explicitly bind the socket to the iP it should use as the source for outgoing connections. If you don't do this it will use the default address of the outgoing interface. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-bind.php

Comment: I would use this function to fit the script below, but I can not implement it, can you help me?

Script : https://github.com/zytzagoo/smtp-validate-email

Thank you in advance

Comment: "can you help me" - If you have problems post what you've tried, explain what kind of problems you have and make sure that your questions and explanations are short but easy to understand and that any code samples have a proper formatting. Don't expect anybody to read and debug your whole program but restrict yourself to the important parts. If you do all of these there is usually somebody able and willing to help you.